# UI automation to take actions on directing to a third party website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, automation, ui-automation

I want to know whether there is a way to take an action ( ex: clicking a button ) when directing to a third party website (ex: facebook.com ) from our website.

Ex: When someone clicks the Facebook icon on my website, it directs to a Linkedin page while opening the chat with a draft message.

Comment: I assume you want to click a linkedin icon to go to linkedin

You would need to look at the [Facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/) or [LinkedIn API](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/)

Comment: I hope this can be done with UI automation thing. What I want is to know how we can do that?

Comment: Only through an api  - possibly through a proxy on your server

Comment: I don't think there is an API on Linkedin to perform this particular task. When the user opens a Linkedin profile via a button click on my site, I need to automatically open the chat of Linkedin and paste my message there, but not to send the message.

Answer (score 1):

No. At least not in the general case.

If it was possible to build a UI automation tool into a webpage which could take actions on completely different sites then you could set things up so that clicking a button on your site would cause my browser to visit my bank's website and transfer you money.

Browser vendors take some [basic security precautions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) to prevent that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you suggest to me a way do my specific task? When the user opens a Linkedin profile via a button click on my site, I need to automatically open the chat of Linkedin and paste my message there, but not to send the message.

Comment: It wasn't possible 8 minutes ago. It isn't possible now.

Comment: Alight. Thanks a lot.